# Running protractor test parallel against different environments/URLs

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I want to run my protractor test specs on different setup, like

test on local env, 
test on test env,
test on production environment and so on in parallel.

So in this case my base URL would change for every environment: When I run the test I would like to run it parallel on all the different environments.

baseUrl:'localhost:8080'
baseUrl:'tst.xxx.com'
baseUrl:'prod.xxx.com'

Can we have a unique job per site where site name is passed as arg of 'npm test'. Do we have any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the basic approach would be to have one job and pass the `baseUrl` as a CLI argument to a `npm task` or Protractor triggering command.

`npm run test -- --baseUrl tst.xxx.com`

Or you can build the logic in your `onPrepare()` to construct `baseUrl` accordingly